# Multiple time sliders in plotly

Tags: time-series, plotly, tableau-api, geospatial, arcgis

I'm trying to plot a spatial temporal map. Using the dataframe, I can make one time slider using plotly_express.

```
px.scatter_mapbox(df, 
                  lat='LATITUDE', 
                  lon='LONGITUDE', 
                  animation_frame='month_year_st', 
)
```

Can I have two time sliders so that I can see the data both year wise by fixing the month, and month-wise by fixing the year in the same plot? Any other tools such as Tableau or Arcgis will also do if it is not feasible in plotly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX3ft.png)

Comment: Looks like it should be possible in vanilla plotly. See here: https://community.plotly.com/t/one-graph-depends-on-multiple-sliders-problem-resolved/26962/3 And there is probably a way to get callbacks to work with the plotly express figure.